# Getting error "Timeouts can be caused by AngularJS services $http and $timeout which fail to complete quick enough."

Tags: protractor

I have wrote a function which technically and logically is correct and while running it runs perfectly locally. But on server I am getting the above error which I could not figure out. I am on protractor version 1.6.0 as same as server but still not able to figure out what causes this.

Scenario is like, I have created many it functions inside my spec.js. But when I ran my spec starting two it functions execute precisely, but on third it scripts fails with above error on server. But when I ran the same spec on my local system with similar settings and configuration, it runs smoothly. Please give me any suggestion if you have encounter the same issue earlier. You can also share the link of a blog if you have any. I am a newbie. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you able to post the code for the function as well as the exact error message you see on your server?

Answer (score 0):

Actually , I did a mistake, when we use non angular locators we have to use findElementDriver instead of findElement. Locally, its runs whithout any issues but on server it gives the above error.